# Knockout Observable in Observable gets re-wrapped when passed to a Component

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

If pass an observable property contained within an observable object to a custom component, then it appears that it gets re-wrapped in a new observable. This causes an issue when you have an extension on the observable like validation.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jaytre/0exas0ug/

```
<div id='main'>
    <foo-check params="value: fooVal"></foo-check> <!-- works -->
    <foo-check params="value: outerVal.fooVal"></foo-check> <!-- works -->
    <foo-check params="value: outerObsrvVal().fooVal"></foo-check> <!-- doesn't work, fooVal gets re-wrapped in new observable -->
</div>
```

Is it a bug in KnockoutJS or is this expected behavior?

Comment: I'm glad you asked this, as I've been meaning to look at components for ages.  It seems that this is expected behaviour - [see the `observableExpression` example here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#passing-observable-expressions).  Haven't posted this as an answer as it's new to me, hopefully someone more versed in it can explain more, but it does seem to explain the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: I think you're right that it is processing the sub-property as an observableExpression & wrapping it in a computed. If I nest this within a <div data-bind="with: outerObsrvVal"> it works fine. Not very intuitive, but I think I understand it... Thanks!

Comment: This is by design, see also in http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/06/knockout-3-2-preview-components.html in the How params are passed to the component section